# How does image sizing work?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm not the best at using bootstrap but trying to learn. I have a row and 3 col-md-4's I put a image in each column and they look and  fit great with the thumbnail class. But without that class the images are their full size and overlap and when I scale the browser down they stay big and you have to use the scroll arrow. I thought the col-md-4 would determine the display of the image but it seems not. When not using the thumbnail class do I have to just resize my photos to the size I want them to display? Please help me understand. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try using `max-width="100%"` (or the class `img-responsive`). See the [bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive) for more info.

Comment: I tryed the img-responsive and no change and 100% width does just that.